# Checking Empty String in Perl

Tags: perl, string

I am just looking for some advice on best practice. What is the best way to check for strings that are empty or include nothing but space character in them?

I generally use regex like this `$string =~/^\s*$/` to see if the variable is blank. Is there a more accepted way or this is as good as any other? Is it better to use regex or to chomp and then check for empty string?

Thanks.

Comment: `chomp` and the regex do not yield identical results...

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I generally invert the sense, and search for a single non-whitespace character.  So I'd say something like:

```
next unless $string =~ /\S/;
```

As ikegami mentioned, `\s` (and `\S`) can be a bit idiosyncratic about exactly what characters are considered whitespace, and you can use `\p{Whitespace}` (or in my case `\P{Whitespace}`) for more consistent results.

Out of curiosity, I benchmarked `not /\S/` versus `/^\s*\z/`.  On an 80 character string (with Perl 5.14.2), I found `not /\S/` was about 20% faster for strings of spaces, and `/^\s*\z/` was about 30% faster for strings of non-spaces.  It's unlikely that checking for blank lines is the bottleneck in your program, but it certainly doesn't hurt to use a simpler regexp.

```
use Benchmark 'cmpthese';

our $text = ' ' x 80;
#our $text = 'abcd' x 20;

cmpthese(-3, {
    'pos'  => '$text =~ /^\s*\z/',
    'neg'  => 'not $text =~ /\S/',
    'negU' => 'not $text =~ /\P{Whitespace}/',
});
```

Example results for spaces:

```
          Rate  pos negU  neg
pos  3562012/s   --  -2% -15%
negU 3651619/s   3%   -- -13%
neg  4194275/s  18%  15%   --
```

Example results for non-spaces:

```
          Rate negU  neg  pos
negU 4951234/s   --  -3% -24%
neg  5112271/s   3%   -- -22%
pos  6555251/s  32%  28%   --
```

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly fine (although `/^\s*\z/` would be less redundant).

Note: It won't match Vertical Tab (U+000B). You can use `\p{Whitespace}` for that.

Note: A bug makes it only match No-Break Space (U+00A0) some of the time unless `use 5.012;` or `/u` is used. `\p{Whitespace}` isn't subject to that bug.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time answering the question.